# Buttonclick event based on DataGrid selected value

Tags: c#, wpf, events, datagrid, selecteditem

I am making a small application for personal use to practice WPF and C#.  The application will launch games (or other applications) based on file paths which are stored in a SQL table.  My SQL connection works fine and the data is retrieved.

```
string query = "SELECT Title, [Path] FROM GOG.dbo.Games";
```

I am using a DataGrid control to display the list of games, and their paths.  I have a ‘Launch Game’ button which I would like to get the currently highlighted item in the DataGrid (i.e. the Path) and then take the path string and therefore run it using the Process.Start() method.

Here’s what I have on my Button_Click but I can’t get it to work:

```
private void LaunchButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string gamePath = dataGrid1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    Process.Start(gamePath);
}
```

Debug says “gamePath "System.Data.DataRowView" string”, and not the value of the actual path e.g: “C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe” which I think is why the application bugs out saying “The system cannot find the file specified” because “System.Data.DataRowView” is of course not a valid program.

How can I get it to put the correct string through instead of “System.Data.DataRowView”?

Comment: to what is the datagrid binded ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dataGrid1.SelectedItem` gives you `System.Data.DataRowView` object. So you can use it directly as string. you must get path from it like following.

```
private void LaunchButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var row=dataGrid1.SelectedItem as System.Data.DataRowView;
    if(row!=null)
    {
       string gamePath = row["Path"].ToString();
       Process.Start(gamePath);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

cast selected item of `DataGrid` to `DataRowView`

```
DataRowView row = (DataRowView)dataGrid1.SelectedItem;
```

then

```
row["ColumnName"];
```